# IP Based Rate Limiting for a TCP passthrough vip

Tags: nginx, tcp

Trying to set this up for one of the applications. We use Nginx under the hood. Is it possible to set up an IP-based rate limiting for a TCP passthrough VIP?

I understand that it is possible to set this up for a regular HTTPS vip, where the certificate terminates at the DLB.